# How is memory layout shared with other processes/threads?

Tags: c, heap-memory, memory-layout

I'm currently learning memory layout in C. For now I know there exist several sections in C program memory: `text`, `data`, `bss`, `heap` and `stack`. They also say `heap` is shared with other things beyond the program.

My questions are these.

1. What exactly is the `heap` shared with? One source states that *Heap must always be freed in order to make it available for **other processes*** whereas another says *The heap area is shared by all threads, shared libraries, and dynamically loaded modules **in a process**.* If it is not shared with other processes, do I really have to free it while my program is running (not at the end of it)?
2. Some sources also single out high addresses (the sixth section) for command line arguments and environment variables. Shall this be considered as another layer and a part of a program memory?
3. Are the other sections shared with anything else beyond a program?

Comment: Re “I know there exist several sections in C programme memory: `text`, `data`, `bss`, `heap` and `stack`”: What document said there was a section named “heap”?

Comment: @EricPostpischil well call it `pool` then, or what do you mean?

Comment: Each process has its own heap, mapped to virtualized chunks of memory requested from the OS. It would be quite bizarre if you could access other processes' heaps from your program. It is also typically freed after only your process exists. Theoretically, your C memory manager might be able to return parts of it earlier, but since memory is usually virtualized by the OS, it just complicates things for no actual benefit.

Comment: @Kaiyakha: I would like to know what document said that. Was it a textbook? A Unix specification? A manual page? Does it have a title, author, publication date, version?

Comment: @EricPostpischil all I can do is just quote TAOCP p. 435: _Several authors began about 1975 to call the pool of available memory a "heap." But in the present series of books, we will use that word only in its more traditional sense related to priority queues._ I have no idea where it came from, but nowadays seems like it is quite widespread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `heap` is a **per-process** memory: each process has its own heap, which is shared only within the same *process space* (like between the process *threads*, as you said). Why should you free it? Not properly to give space to other processes (at least in modern OS where the process memory is reclaimed by the OS when the process dies), but to prevent heap exhaustion within your process memory: in C, if you don't deallocate the heap memory regions you used, they will be always considered as busy even when they are not used anymore. Thus, to prevent undesired errors, it's a good practice to free the memory in the heap as soon as you don't need it anymore.
2. In a C program the command line variables are stored in the stack as *function variables* of the **main**. What happens is that usually the stack is allocated in the highest portion of a process memory, which is mapped to the high addresses (this is probably the reason why some sources point out what you wrote). But, generally speaking, there isn't any sixth memory area.
3. As said by the others, the `text` area can be shared by processes. This area usually contains the binary code, which would be the same for different processes which share the same binary. For performance reasons, the OS can allow to share such memory area, (think for example when you `fork` a child process).

Comment: And the other layers are not shared even between threads of the same process, right?

Comment: Threads share everything except the `stack`: each thread has its own stack (even though the different threads stacks are placed within the same *process stack*, often contiguously). But a thread cannot access the stack of a sibling thread, otherwise a memory exception would be raised.

Answer (score 1):

1. Heap is shared with other processes in a sense that all processes use RAM. The more of it you use, the less is available to other programs. Heap sharing with other threads in your own program means that all your threads actually see and access the same heap (same virtual address space, same actual RAM, with some luck also same cache).
2. No.
3. `text` can be shared with other processes. These days it is marked as read-only, so having several processes share `text` makes sense. In practice this means that if you are already running `top` and you run another instance it makes no sense to load `text` part again. This would waste time and physical RAM. If the OS is smart enough it can map those RAM pages into virtual address space of both `top` instances, saving time and space.

Comment: What is `top` here?

Comment: Linux tool that shows you current usage of CPU, processes running, etc. Just an example of a process that runs for a while. Want a simpler one? How about `sleep`?

Comment: I'm just not a Linux user :) By `processes` I meant any other running programme, isn't that correct?

Comment: Not a problem. On Windows, let's say you are watching two movies at the same time using VLC. That means that `vlc.exe` only needs to reside in RAM once.

Comment: Now it's clear. And one last question! If `heap` is shared with other programmes, can it be as large as the entire RAM (or close to that)?

Comment: Be careful here. To most this statement would indicate that one program has access to `heap` of another program. This is not the case. As I said, they all share RAM, meaning that at one moment process 1 may occupy a RAM page and in the next moment another process may occupy that page.

Comment: `heap` can in fact be larger than physical RAM due to magic of swapping, but that will slow your machine to a crawl.

Comment: So practically each process has its own heap and they do not share the same heap?

Comment: Correct. It would be a security issue if they did.

Comment: Well then not only _Heap is shared with other processes in a sense that all processes use RAM_, but the other layers as well, aren't they? They use the same RAM as well, don't they?

Comment: They do. In the end everything is in RAM. However, let's say that you either don't have swap or that you reached its limit. In that case you can't get more heap. If swap is already fully utilized then you can't swap anything out from RAM do swap file so no more heap (or stack) for you. However, you can mostly throw executable code out of RAM. If you need it you can always reload it from the executable file from which it came in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

**On the official aspect:**

The terms *thread*, *process*, *text section*, *data section*, *bss*, *heap* and *stack* are not even defined by the C language standard, and every platform is free to implement these components however "it may like".

Threads and processes are typically implemented at the operating-system layer, while all the different memory sections are typically implemented at the compiler layer.

**On the practical aspect:**

For every given process, all these memory sections (text section, data section, bss, heap and stack) are shared by all the threads of that process.

Hence, it is under the responsibility of the programmer to ensure mutual-exclusion when accessing these memory sections from different threads.

Typically, this is achieved via synchronization utilities such as semaphores, mutexes and message queues.

In between processes, it is under the responsibility of the operating system to ensure mutual-exclusion.

Typically, this is achieved via virtual-memory abstraction, where each process runs inside its own logical address space, and each logical address space is mapped to a different physical address space.

Disclaimer: some would claim that each thread has its own stack, but technically speaking, those stacks are usually allocated consecutively on the stack of the process, and there's usually no one to prevent a thread from accessing the stacks of other threads, whether intentionally or by mistake (aka *stack overflow*).